# Controller Target Class does not exist?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

Im trying to follow a larval tutorial and make a controller. This is what I have so far and it works for the guy in the video but mine says controller not found. I don't know what to do to fix it. Thank you!

**web.php file:**

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'home']);
```

**PagesController.php file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;




class PagesController extends Controller
{
    public function home() 
    {
        return view('welcome', [
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ]);
    }
}
```

[PagesController.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2vTk.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEhYY.png)

[Web.php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfHMc.png)

Comment: Can you try run "composer dump-autoload" then try again.

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you get this error when doing what?

Answer (score 1):

I think somethings it happens due to cache of routes you added before

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Command to clear all cache

And then check does this get('/') route is binded to home() method on conrtoller using

```
php artisan route:list
```

I hope its resolve your issue..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController` in web.php file?

If it doesn't exist, you should type it top of the file.

Comment: This fixed my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

why did you use this in PagesController.php :

`use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController;`

This is wrong. you must remove this line of code in PagesController.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, added.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\PagesController
```

to the top of my web.php file and changed the get route to

```
Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'home']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `Route::get('/', [PagesController::class, 'home']);`

you should use `Route::get('/', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@home');`

If you do not want to type full namespace location just open RouteServiceProvider.php and add following `$namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`

Hope this solves your problem